# how can I bind "Control"+"Return" to "Evaluate Notebook"

Tags: keyboard

## how can I bind "Control"+"Return" to "Evaluate Notebook"

---

### *Attempt1*

I tried by modifying `KeyEventTranslations.tr` and restarting my computer.
To no avail :(

```
 (* Evaluation *)
Item[KeyEvent["Enter"], "EvaluateCells"], 
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter"], "EvaluateCells"], 
Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "HandleShiftReturn"],
Item[KeyEvent["KP_Enter"], "EvaluateCells"], 
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"],    
Item[KeyEvent["KP_Enter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"],   
Item[KeyEvent["Enter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"],
```

> Item[KeyEvent[`"Return"`, Modifiers -> {`Control`}], Evaluate[All]],

```
Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Option}], "SimilarCellBelow"], 
Item[KeyEvent[".", Modifiers->{Command, Option}], FrontEnd`EvaluatorInterrupt[Automatic]], 
Item[KeyEvent["Escape"], "ShortNameDelimiter"],
```

---

### *Attempt2*

I also tried adding a shortcut for the menu command "Evaluate Notebook" using OS X

> System Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

[image]

I notice that other keyboard shortcuts work for this command. But <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RETURN</kbd> seems to be bound to something else!

Comment: There does seem to be something special about that shortcut - I can easily bind, for example, `<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>` to "Evaluate Notebook" using the second method

Comment: KeyEventTranslations.tr already has a binding for Ctrl+Return. Also, MenuSetup.tr has a binding for Ctrl+Return. I think you need to remove both of these first.